# dplyr::left_join on variables of different type

Tags: r, dplyr

Can I join two datasets without mutating one of the variables in a prior step? For instance can I manipulate the by clause?

```
# qsec is a double by default
mt1 <- mtcars %>% mutate(qsec = as.character(qsec))

# successful join with prior mutate
mt1 %>% 
  mutate(qsec = as.double(qsec)) %>%
  left_join(mtcars, by = c('qsec' = 'qsec'))

# failed join of character to double
left_join(mt1, mtcars, by = c('qsec' = as.character('qsec')))
```

Comment: No, you can't manipulate variables in the by clause - it's just a (named) character vector of column names.

Comment: There are countless times and reasons why this can go poorly within `left_join` (and related), and every reason to require that the user handle these special cases themselves before attempting to join. Many join/merge implementations (e.g., SQL) will manually coerce in the case of imperfect matches; for example SQLite (via `sqldf`) will convert to character if either column is a character. I've found that these coersions can *mask* problems about the underlying data, where assumptions are not correct. In these cases, problems have resulted, and tracking the cause is harder when SQL does this.